# iOS - two apps on same device communicating with single Bluetooth device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I was wondering if it is possible for two apps on the same device to send and recieve data to a single bluetooth device?  For example, one app communicating with the Bluetooth device in the foreground while another app is receiving data from the Bluetooth device in the background.

Comment: you can easily test this. the app in the background will have limitations

Comment: The bluetooth device I am working with can't currently handle multiple connections, but before modifying the device it to work with multiple connections, I wanted to figure out if there was a point.  Because if there is a limitation in the OS, then there is no point in making the change in the bluetooth device.

Comment: The person who answered this question said it can't.  Can anybody verify if that is correct?  I

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456479/can-two-apps-running-simultaneously-on-the-same-idevice-communicate-through-blue

Comment: Here is a person that has an issue that suggests that it can't, but nobody answered his question.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5648738?tstart=0